# Trying to consume a web service

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/write-web-service).

I created an ASP.NET Web Application and added a Web Service called MathService where I added the methods mentioned in the tutorial.

Then I created a console application and added a service reference to the MathService I've created (using OpenAPI)

Then I tried to modify the Main function as mentioned in the tutorial, but I got this error: "the type or namespace localhost doesn't exist". (in the tutorial is says that I should find the name of the namespace in Web References section, but I don't have/see this section)

I've modified the default Main function like this (before it only included a line for printing "Hello World"):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            localhost.Service1 myMathService = new localhost.Service1();
            Console.Write("2 + 4 = {0}", myMathService.Add(2, 4));
        }
```

Here's the project structure:

[image]

Comment: *"Then I tried to modify the Main function as mentioned in the tutorial, but I got this error: "the type or namespace localhost doesn't exist"."* - We don't know what modifications you make or what your code looked like before the modifications.  Please include relevant code demonstrating the problem.  Indicate which specific line of code generates the error, where you expect `localhost` to be defined, and any other information about the problem.

Comment: Where is `localhost` or `Service1` defined?  How did you add a reference to the server in the console app?  Is the service class really called `Service1` and not `MathService`?  If you remove the `localhost` part and just use the class name (`Service1` in the code shown), can you use Visual Studio to automatically add a reference to the namespace?  (Normally by right-clicking on it, or clicking on a small UI indicator of the error.)